# Where can I find implementation details for .Net classes?

Tags: .net

MSDN is a great resource for how to use classes in the .Net library, but can I find out how they're implemented internally? If so, where?

Comment: Well, as the .NET framework isn't open source, I think the only way is reverse engineering...and I'm not sure it's legal.

Comment: well, considering Microsoft is privative, this could be complicated.. I'm not sure if you can get this

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/378498/can-i-reflector-the-net-base-class-libraries-bcl

Comment: @Bartdude: Microsoft provides the code of the .NET framework.

Comment: @Erno yep, my bad, that's why I made it a remark not an answer. I didn't know Microsoft was so open about their source code, although I could have guessed knowing there's various implementations of the framework, they must have some kind of reference...

Comment: @Gonzalo.-: See http://referencesource.microsoft.com/netframework.aspx

Answer (score 6):

Go here: http://referencesource.microsoft.com/netframework.aspx

If it is not there you can use a decompiler such as [dotPeek](http://www.jetbrains.com/decompiler/)

Answer (score 1):

you can use programs like [ILSpy](http://ilspy.net/) to look at assemblies

Answer (score 1):

You can try ILSpy. It decompiles a .NET assembly.

see: http://ilspy.net/